# Linear Algebra: Is det({{M,F},{F, M})<0 when det(M)=0?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Suppose that $M$ and $F$ are real matrices. Let $A$ be the block-matrix
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
 M  & F \\
 F  & M
\end{pmatrix}
$$
If $\det(M)=0$ is $\det(A)\leq0$? If not, what conditions need to be satisfied?

Also,

Does A have a non-positive eigenvalue?

Comment: The matrix is A = {{M,F},{F,M}}. Sorry, I do not know how to draw the matrix.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question, since I made a slight mistake. Does A have to have a non-positive eigenvalue?

Comment: I have added to my solution about eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$
M=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\quad
F
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then 
$$
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
M & F \\
F & M
\end{pmatrix}=1
$$

Comment: Thanks Brian. What are some (non-trivial) sufficient conditions to ensure det(A)>0?

Comment: Let me rephrase the question, since I made a slight mistake. Does A have to have a non-positive eigenvalue?

Answer (score 2):

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
 M  & F \\
 F  & M
\end{pmatrix}=\det(M-F)\det(M+F),$$

So, if, say $M=0$ and **$F$ is *any* matrix of even order**, $\det -F=\det F$, and

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
 0  & F \\
 F  & 0
\end{pmatrix}=(\det F)^2.$$

---

**Edit.** Since you added the question about eigenvalues.

Eigenvalues of $A$ are determined by the characteristic polynomial roots:

$$0=\det(\lambda\mathbb{I}-A)=\det\begin{pmatrix}
 \lambda\mathbb{I}-M  & -F \\
 -F  & \lambda\mathbb{I}-M
\end{pmatrix}=\det(\lambda\mathbb{I}-M+F)\cdot\det(\lambda\mathbb{I}-M-F).$$

Therefore, the eigenvalues are the combination of eigenvalues of $M-F$ and $M+F$. Now, we see that if $M=0$ then, indeed, for every eigenvalue of $F$ we have the opposite eigenvalue of $-F$. However, if $M$ is arbitrary, even if $\det M=0$, there is no reason for either $M-F$ or $M+F$ to have non-positive eigenvalues.

For example, let's take

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
 a  & a \\
 a  & a
\end{pmatrix},
F=\begin{pmatrix}
 0  & -b \\
 b  & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$(M-F)=(M+F)^T=\begin{pmatrix}
 a  & a+b \\
 a-b  & a
\end{pmatrix}\text{ has real eigenvalues }a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b^2}>0\text{ if }0<b<a.$$

And, indeed,

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 a & a & 0 & -b \\
 a & a & b & 0 \\
 0 & -b & a & a \\
 b & 0 & a & a
\end{pmatrix}\text{ has (double) real eigenvalues }a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b^2}>0\text{ if }0<b<a.$$

Answer (score 0):

$A$ can possess a full set of positive eigenvalues (and hence a positive determinant). For instance, [according to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues%20%7B%7B10,%200,-1,-9%7D,%7B%200,%200,%201,%200%7D,%7B-1,-9,10,%200%7D,%7B%201,%200,%200,%200%7D%7D), all four eigenvalues of the following randomly generated matrix are strictly positive:
$$A=\pmatrix{10&0&-1&-9\\ 0&0&1&0\\ -1&-9&10&0\\ 1&0&0&0}.$$